# Sonar Qube - VB files issue

Tags: vb.net, sonarqube

I have a project in Visual basic, which has a file and it has a variable like

```
Dim data as String = <a><![CDATA[
                <html>
                <body>
                <span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20pt;font-weight:bold">Summary information</span>
                <br/>
            ]]></a>.Value
```

When i pass this project to sonar runner, it is giving lex error.

Version used are Sonar Qube Runner 2.4
Sonar Server 4.5.4

Answer (score 0):

XML literals are not yet supported by the SonarQube VB.NET plugin, you can follow this ticket to be informed of the progress: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/VBNET-3

Comment: thanks, any time line when this will be available. Is there a work around to ignore the error or file from Sonar for this

Comment: well such an error is not supposed to fail the overall analysis: You should simply not see metrics nor SonarQube rules executed on it - but FxCop rules should still be evaluated for example. Let me know if that is not the case for you.

Comment: actually, sonar is giving me as Execution failure with the following  Caused by: com.sonar.sslr.B.C: Unable to lex url: <file name>  To hide this did we need to change some thing ?

Comment: I see - this fatal error is actually caused not by the primary analysis, but by the copy&paste (AKA clone) detector, which you can disable by setting the `sonar.cpd.skip` property as in `sonar-runner -Dsonar.cpd.skip`

Comment: I've created the following ticket to keep track of that limitation: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/VBNET-168

Comment: thanks for this in the sonar.properties i need to mention as sonar.cpd.skip=true right